# Text in UITextView goes out of its frames Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uitextview

The problem is that when I enter some text in my textView 
the text goes out of its set frames.
I am creating everything programatically though.

Creating UITextView:

```
    let descriptionTextView: UITextView = {
    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.customDarkGrayColor
    textView.text = "News Description"
    textView.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15)
    textView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 16)
    textView.autocorrectionType = .no
    textView.setDefaultShadow()
    return textView
}()
```

Adding as subview and Setting Constraints using my custom method:

```
addSubview(descriptionTextView)

descriptionTextView.anchor(top: titleTextField.bottomAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: nil, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 10, paddingLeft: 20, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 20, width: 0, height: 80)
```

[Check the bug here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ynWc.jpg)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A possible idea of where to look into:

- Your `UITextView` is currently scrollable, so the text container has no limit on height
- Since you add a shadow, you probably set `masksToBounds` or `clipsToBounds` to `true` which is why the text appears outside of the view frame.

Let me know if that helps. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you so much buddy for giving me the right tip!
The problem was with setting custom shadow as you've just said. I just removed that and now everything works fine!!! :)

Comment: Glad that helped! Happy coding :)

Comment: Because of this kind of issues, I usually use a wrapper view to display the shadow.

Comment: Hmm I've never heard about this approach.. But thank you for a recommendation!